# Converting template-driven interpolation into more 'Reactive' code

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, validation

So, my current code is working fine as follows (note specifically the div):

```
<label label-top>
  <span>Email Address <span class="required">*</span></span>
    <input class="form-control-input" formControlName="CONTROL_EMAIL" type="text"/>
    <div class="required--error">
    {{this.FormGroupPayAmount.controls.CONTROL_EMAIL.invalid
      && this.FormGroupPayAmount.controls.CONTROL_EMAIL.touched?
        'A valid email is required':''}}
    </div>
</label>
```

While this works, it feels very clunky/hacky. Also it feels very "template-based", and I would like to do it in a more "Reactive" or "Angular" way.

I have tried so many different things "I can't even".  I have been trying to get this to work as a Directive, but then switched to possibly using a signal. I am trying to avoid adding a subscription to the constructor because I actually have a lot of fields to adjust (convert to reactive/angular way) and don't feel like having 10-20 subscriptions in a single form (each one has its own error text). I also can't use *ngIf on the div (unfortunately) because parts of my form are 3rd party iframes and I need to make the form look consistent.

tl;dr: looking for a/the "reactive"/"angular" way to show and hide error text - possibly in a directive?

Comment: I know this doesn't help you now ... but signals are only in their first developer preview and don't currently support two-way binding and forms. From what I understand, there are plans to revisit how signals can improve the form experience.